# Run riverpod provider in background flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod, geolocator

I have a provider which is watching the position changes:

```
@riverpod
Stream<Position> positionStream(
PositionStreamRef ref,
) async* {
final locationService = ref.watch(locationServiceProvider);

yield* locationService.geolocator.getPositionStream(
locationSettings: locationService.getLocationSettings(),
 );
}
```

I then watch the `positionStreamProvider` provider in another provider.

```
@riverpod
Stream<List<MyObject>> myObjectsWithinRadius(MyObjectsWithinRadiusRef ref) {
  final myLocation =
      ref.watch(positionStreamProvider.select((value) => value.valueOrNull));
  return ref
      .watch(myObjectsWithinRadiusRepoProvider(
          myLocation!.latitude, myLocation.longitude))
      .getObjects();
}
```

A key feature of the app is to work in background as well as in foreground, and send notification as soon as an object is found within a certain radius.
I have read about isolate but that seems kind of over complicated.
I have also look at the flutter_background_geolocation package, but it costs more than 300 bucks for the single app license.
Is there a simpler, latest way to get the providers run in the background?

Comment: You won't be able to execute any code while your app is not visible unless it's running in a non-ui isolate, and even then the execution will be limited, and possibly terminated at will by the operating system.  Perhaps if you can describe your goals better, we can help better.

Comment: You would need to work with a native package or create your own so you can run your code in background, maybe check workmanager and geolocator to see if there is a way to combine them

Comment: WorkManager is not an option because I need the background task to run more often than every 15 minutes